# Can not copy folders in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The problem is that when copying the files in the netscan.zip file to the usb.
It unzip all to root.

This is how the files looks in KHtemp folder:

```
c:\Data\install\     <-  Files
c:\Data\info         <-  Files
c:\Knowhow.exe
```

But when the copying is done i looks like this on the usb

```
\knohow.exe
\data\
\intall\
\info\
```

I can not find out what iam doing wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KHupdater
{
    public partial class Install : Form
    {
        public Install()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Close.Visible = false;

        }


        //  COPY
        #region  copy

        public static void CopyFolder(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
            // Copy files first.
            foreach (var sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
            {
                string destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile));
                File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
            }
            foreach (var sourceSubPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath))
            {
                string destPath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, sourceSubPath.Substring(sourcePath.Length));
                CopyFolder(sourceSubPath, destPath);
            }
        }






        #endregion

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Start.Visible = false;
            Loadingbar.Visible = true;

            string tempfolder = "C:\\KHtemp";
            string tempfile = @"c:\KHtemp\Update.zip";



            // If the 'tempfolder' exists it will be deleted

            if (Directory.Exists(tempfolder))
            {
                Directory.Delete("c:\\KHtemp", true);
            }

            Loadingbar.Value = (10);



            // Make Folder and download file
            if (!Directory.Exists(tempfolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempfolder);
            }
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile("http://67.327.195.57/netscan.zip", @"c:\KHtemp\Update.zip");

            Loadingbar.Value = (50);


            // Unrar files in to 'tempfolder'
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(tempfile, tempfolder);

            // Del rar file from 'tempfolder' 
            File.Delete("c:\\KHtemp\\Update.zip");
            //  !?

            Loadingbar.Value = (70);

            // Copy files to USB 
            var StartupPath = Application.StartupPath;
            var root = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(StartupPath);



            // Copy All files from 'tempfolder' to root of the USB

            foreach (var sourceFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(tempfolder))
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
                string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(root, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, true);

                CopyFolder(tempfolder, root);
            }

            Loadingbar.Value = (90);


            //// Del 'tempfolder'
            Directory.Delete("c:\\KHtemp", true);

            //// 

            this.Loadingbar.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;



            // Show message when done
              Loadingbar.Value = (100);
            label1.Text = "Update is Done";
            Close.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var StartupPath = Application.StartupPath;
            var root = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(StartupPath);
            var Knowhowfile = "Knowhow.exe";

            var Knowhow = Process.Start(root + Knowhowfile);

            Environment.Exit(1);

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do the folder names have a `.` in their name? Do you get any exceptions or warnings thrown?

Comment: No, this code work from start to end. but i will not copy the subfolders in the c:\KHtemp

Comment: Do the subfolders have a `.` in their name @Tobbe ? Had a similar problem when moving folders, as System.IO.File seems to have issues and will consider those folders as files

Comment: No... in this exempel the folder i called "data"  and "info"

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy each folder as well - something like this will work:

```
public static void CopyFolder(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
     // Copy files first.
     foreach(var sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
     {
          string destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile));
          File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
     }
     foreach(var sourceSubPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath))
     {
          string destPath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(sourceSubPath));
          CopyFolder(sourceSubPath, destPath);
     }
}
```

You should call CopyFolder(tempFolder, root)

Please note that it is not tested, you need to debug the CopyFolder method to verify e.g. destPath

Comment: When using this it will copy the folder and the subfolder to the root of the usb.  So i will get like a F:\info\  but it looks like this C:\KHtemp\data\info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the current item in loop is File or Directory.
If it's a file then write a code of copy and if it's a directory then create it manually by using `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("");`